# How to populate a json file from a list in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, csv

I got a CSV file that I want to rearange in a specific manner and then save as JSON.

I've been able to put the information från the csv file into python lists. The problem arise when I try to populate the Json file. I don't understand how to add the lists content to the JSON file.

CSV file:

```
2010.03.01,00:00,1.0,1.1
2010.03.01,04:00,2.0,2.1
2010.03.01,08:00,3.0,3.1
```

Desired JSON outcome:

```
{"Base number":23,"In stock":"Yes","timestamp":[1267398000,1267412400,1267426800],"float1":[1.0,2.0,3.0],"float2":[1.1,2.1,3.1]}
```

My phython code:

```
import csv
import json
import datetime

dates = []
float1 = []
float2 = []

with open(csvFile.csv) as csvDataFile:
    csvReader = csv.reader(csvDataFile)
    for row in csvReader:
        #Date and time to timestamp
        timestamp = int(datetime.datetime.strptime(' '.join([row[0], row[1]]), '%Y.%m.%d %H:%M').timestamp())
        dates.append(timestamp)

        #Float value
        float1.append(float(row[2]))
        float2.append(float(row[3]))

data = {
    "Base number": 23,
    "In stock": "Yes",
}
with open(jsonFile.json, 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're almost there. You can just update the `data` dictionary like so:

```
data = {
    "Base number": 23,
    "In stock": "Yes",
    "float1": float1,
    "float2": float2,
    "timestamp": dates
}
```

The json dump should contain the lists you created now. Also make sure that you open the json file correctly (just changing `jsonFile.json` to `"jsonFile.json"` should work)

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly well. I was soo close. :)